# wpf databinding and x:Arrays

Tags: wpf, arrays, data-binding

I try to make some databinding involving an x:Array defined in the resources, but somehow, it doesn't work even the code is compiling.
In the resources, I define an array of Strings this way:

```
<x:Array x:Key="ArrayReportType" Type="{x:Type sys:String}">
    <sys:String>Energy Export</sys:String>
    <sys:String>Cost Center Report</sys:String>
</x:Array>
```

I've also a collection of objects. One of the property is called "ReportType" and is an integer/enum.
So I'd like to make a databinding to show the corresponding string to the ReportType instead of the int/enum.
I tried this line, but it doesn't work (the second line causes the pb):

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Type"
                    Binding="{Binding Source={StaticResource ArrayReportType}, Path=[{Binding ReportType}]}" />
```

I'm sure, I'm close to the solution. If I write directly "Path=[1]", then it's correct.
During runtime, I receive this error:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: '[]' property not found on 'object' ''String[]' (HashCode=14199578)'. BindingExpression:Path=[{Binding ReportType}]; DataItem='String[]' (HashCode=14199578); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok to use a DataGridComboBoxColumn?

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Type"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ArrayReportType}}">
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="{Binding ReportType}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="{Binding ReportType}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

**Update**
Readonly text cell

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Type"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ArrayReportType}}"
                        IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="{Binding ReportType}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Comment: Well, it was one of my idea as workaround.
But if possible, I'd like to "simply" display the string in the cell.
WPF is so powerful, that should be possible!

Comment: Yes, you were quicker than me!! I just saw, if I set it to readonly, then, the comboxbox simply appears as normal text!!
Thx a lot!

Comment: Well, one more question: how can I make this column sortable?!? What should I put in "SortMemberPath"?

Comment: @Fred: I tried it and it seems to work fine when using SortMemberPath="ReportType". That gives me ascending/descending Sorting by index. How do you want it sorted?

Comment: Well, that's the point. I want it sorted by "String" and not by Index.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can resolve this with a dedicated converter.

Something like that?

```
<DataGridTextColumn 
    Header="Type"
    Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource IndexToArrayItemConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource ArrayReportType}, Path=ReportType}"/>
```

*Converter code skipped for being so obvious*

Comment: Well, it could be a solution, but ... I have to write a converter! I'd like a 100% xaml solution!

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do it in pure XAML. `Path=[?]` probably expects a constant or a property, not a binding extension.